# Iron:Router add events on change router

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like add classe on different route current.

My script :

```
Template.layout.rendered({

    rowClass: function() {

        var blockGridContent = [
            'blogPostDetail',
            'contact'
        ];

        // Si on est sur l'une des pages de 'blockGridContent'
        if (_.contains(blockGridContent, routeCurrent)) {

            return 'block-grid';

        }

    }

})
```

This code work good, but only onload. If I get on the " test" and I change page, the class remains.

I think I have to check from server or iron : router , but I do not know how.

Do you have idea ?

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad practice to try to access current route from inside of your components, that makes them harder to maintain. Instead, you should pass them all the needed data.

In your case, you can achieve what you need with your controller's `data` method:

```
BlockGridController = RouteController.extend({
  ...
  data: function() {
    return {
      ...
      layout: {style: 'block-grid'},
    };
  },
});
```

Then access it in the layout template:

```
<div class="{{layout.style}}">
```

Comment: Hi Hubert. I've try this, but it's don't work. Maybe because i've already data after my controller ?

Comment: If you've got another controller extending from this one and overriding the data method, then yes, it won't work without one additional step. You need to explicitly extend the existing data object in child controller. The easiest way I know to do so is to create a custom method in the parent controller for the data handling, i.e. `groupData`, and then in child `data` method extend `this.groupData()` object.